# RewriteRules stop working when I add a VirtualHost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration, virtualhost

I have a bunch of RewriteRules that are working fine, and must exist to every hostname that the server replies to. An example:

```
RewriteRule ^/file\.js /var/pear/Package/file\.js [QSA,L]
```

Now, I wanted to force canonical names for the missing-slash-at-end-of-directory redirects. So I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName custom.name.com
</VirtualHost>
```

That results if I go to http://custom.name.com/some_dir it redirects to http://custom.name.com/some_dir/

now, if i go to http://custom.name.com/file.js or http://original.host.name/file.js I get a 404 instead of the file in Pear. If I remove the VirtualHost 3 lines, everything goes back working.

Any ideas why?

Edit 1:

tried ServerAlias instead of ServerName, same result.

Edit2:

Just setting a VirtualHost cause the RewriteRules to stop working. An empty is already enough.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your rule works only for the default site.

try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName custom.name.com
  DocumentRoot path/goes/here
  <Directory "path/goes/here">
     ...
     RewriteRule ^/file\.js /home/y/share/pear/Pacakge/file\.js [QSA,L]
     ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this help you

Regards